# AngularJs List attribute does not work in internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-11

I have a scope that I am using `find` . It is working in `chrome` but not in `Internet explorer 11`
how can I make it work in IE 11?

```
$scope.NameList= [];

$scope.addRow = function () {
    if ($scope.NameList.find(findName)) {
        $scope.error = "Already in the list";
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the docs on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: try using `.indexOf`

Comment: but my list is a list of objects, how can I use indexof in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer does not support `find` method on Array. You have to use `indexOf` and then access the key (if exists).

Comment: but my list is a list of objects, how can I use indexof in this case?

Comment: @user3122648 You can use `filter` method to filter objects in array and find the one you're looking for or you can use `find` method in `lodash` library, or you can download a polyfill of `find` method for IE, which can be found here, for instance, https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim